# What ecommerce platforms support decimal product quantities?

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart, webshop

I am working on a client site and the majority of what they sell is fabric sold by the yard, with a minimum of .25 yards per purchase.

The client INSISTS that he wants the end user to enter a decimal into the quantity field to order the amount of fabric she wants and so far I haven't been able to talk him out of this requirement.

They currently use Miva because it supports this particular requirement (through a  [module](http://www.mivacentral.com/Merchant2/merchant.mv?Screen=PROD&store_code=m&product_code=WCW-SIZEX5&query=http://search.mivacentral.com/search/index?query=size&search.x=0&search.y=0)). I'd prefer not to work with Miva if I can help it, so I'm turning to you guys!

So far, I've found two additional options for handling decimal quantities:

- Magento
- Zen Cart

Anyone know of any other options? I'm open to anything right now (hosted, open source, whatever), just want to see all the options for this one specific weird requirement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could go for TYPO3 Multishop. Also open source and with a tiny adjustment it supports decimals as quantity input. You can see it in action on the following web page:

http://www.bbms.nl/webwinkel/

More information about TYPO3 Multishop can be found here:

http://typo3multishop.com/